# Ruby on Rails: After change in view, website not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I don't think I quite understand how rails updates its view pages. I have deleted a piece of code in my index view, and when I go to refresh page, the code is still present. I tried restarting the server, and I can't think what else to do. Must be a simple thing that I haven't learnt yet, as I'm new to rails. Thanks

EDIT:

Routes

```
    projects GET    /projects(.:format)          projects#index
             POST   /projects(.:format)          projects#create
 new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
     project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
             PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
             DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy
      search        /search(.:format)            projects#search
        root        /                            projects#index
```

config/routes.rb:

```
FinalApp::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :projects
    match "search" => "projects#search", :as => :search
    root :to => 'projects#index'
end
```

Index action in Project Controller:

```
def index
    @projects = Project.all



respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @projects }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it stays the same after editing the html, you are not viewing what you think you are viewing.

- Maybe you have both a index.html.erb and a index.html.haml file?
- Are you sure you did not accidently copy the index.html.erb outside the app/views/projects/ folder, so Rails takes the one in that location?

Comment: There was text that was the same colour as the background. Saw it when I highlighted everything. D'oh!

Comment: also check that your indentation is consistent. Forgetting an editorconfig on a collaborated project can really waste your time with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the index.html file present in the public folder of your app.

Comment: There is no index.html present in the public folder :/

Comment: You can even check the format.html render :action => "abcd". Then you need to change the abcd.html file from the same controller.

Comment: I have updated my question. I am using Chrome, and just tried firefox, and it is the same

Comment: Try looking for the content in the layout file present in the layout folder then.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your `config/routes.rb` points #index to the right controller and action.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a tutorial and had run `rails server` in the directory outside of `app`. I'm pretty sure I stopped and started the server a couple of times, navigated around directories, then I made some changes and they weren't showing. I stopped the server, changed into `app` then started the server again, I got what I expected. If you're having trouble, it might be worth checking that.